# Mini Page Layout CSS in Visualforce Page

Tags: css, salesforce, apex-code

I've a VF Page which uses a Apex `StandardSetController()` to display the list of a Standard Object Records(Case in my Page). The mini page layout which is a standard functionality from Salesforce has some CSS issues.

On Hover, the mini page layout appears as expected but the position is absolute. I've scroll-able view, so when I hover on records after scrolling(on those which were hidden previously), the mini page layout is shown at the absolute position and not at the current position.

I'm sure that it has nothing to do with the `StandardSetController()`. Is there a CSS patch for this situation. Will it be a proper way to alter the Standard CSS since the classes and the CSS might be changed from the Salesforce side in a newer releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe you can apply the correct CSS to adjust the mini page, find what the miini page  div class or ID is and put the corrected CSS in a style tag at the top of the visualforce page.

```
<apex:page>
<style>
div.minipagelayout { position:relative; } or something
</style>
...
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think you should change `<script>` by `<style>`.

Comment: Thats exactly my question. Is it the right way? To use the classes as used by Salesforce, because there is a possibility that the class name might be renamed or DOM structure changes can be done at their end in newer releases.

Comment: @Vignesh Well, it is a possibility, unfortunately, there is no way for you to change what THEY call it, so all you can do is overwrite their settings. While it is a possibility that they could change it, the UI names and classes are practically fixed until they release a new UI theme. But until that time, i believe this is the only method available to us.